# Why do Mark's and Luke's quotations of the Greatest Commandment have four different words instead of three?

Tags: life-of-jesus, love

In both Mark's and Luke's accounts of Jesus identification of the Greatest Commandment, they lists four different words rather than three, which Matthew lists and the Deuteronomy passage which they quote has as well.

> And he answered, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your **heart** and with all your **soul** and with all your **strength** and with all your **mind**, and your neighbor as yourself.”  Luke 10:27 ESV
>
> And you shall love the Lord your God with all your **heart** and with all your **soul** and with all your **mind** and with all your **strength**.’  Mark 12:30 ESV
>
> And he said to him, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your **heart** and with all your **soul** and with all your **mind**.  Matthew 22:37 ESV
>
> You shall love the Lord your God with all your **heart** and with all your **soul** and with all your **might**.  Deuteronomy 6:5 ESV

So, why do Mark and Luke mention four words rather than three?